# CKEditor: how to remove the autoembed behavior when pasting an url in the text section (4.7 version)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor version 4.7.

In the config.js file i integrated some plugins for auto embed link on external sites (es. youtube, twitter, facebook, etc.).

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.extra_plugins = 'widgetselection,notificationaggregator,notification,clipboard,lineutils,widget,dialogui,dialog,embedbase,embed';
};
```

However, for some pages, i saw there is an auto-embed behavior when i copy an url on the text section on ckeditor. and i need to disable it, it would be better if it would be to have this behavior only when I click on the specific icon on the tab. There is a way to appear the iframely embedded only when i click that icon and not when i simply paste the link url on CKEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the solution, there is the property removePlugins to do this for each component, in this case i removed the embedbase and the embed plugins as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('text1', {
       allowedContent : true,
       autoParagraph: false,
       removePlugins: 'embedbase, embed',
       toolbar : [ ['Source'], ['Bold','Italic','Underline'], [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote' ], [ 'Styles', 'Format' ], ]});
```